# Using MyBatis Update with foreach

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

i am struggling with update statement in MyBatis. I want to put multiple strings in one row:

```
UPDATE MY_FILTERS
SET
GROUPS =
  <foreach item="item" collection="selectedGroups" open="" separator="," close="">
    #{item}
  </foreach>,
TEMPLATES = 
  <foreach item="item" collection="selectedTemplates" open="" separator="," close="">
    #{item}
  </foreach>
where ID = #{id}
```

I've tried the following alternatives:

```
open = "'" close = "'"
```

or

```
separator = "','"
```

but still getting exceptions like this:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification 
### The error may involve my.mybatis.PRPMapper.saveParamsToDB-Inline 
### The error occurred while setting parameters 
### SQL: UPDATE MY_FILTERS SET GROUPS = ? , ? , TEMPLATES = ? , ? where ID = ? 
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
open = "'" close = "'"
```

and

```
separator = ","
```

and

```
${item}
```

With these settings mybatis does not bind the variables but performs a String substitution. Be careful that string substittution is vulnerable to sql injection. If you face some more problems please post the updated sql query built by mystatis

Comment: Thank You for response. I am getting:
`org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: ### Error updating database. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index ### The error may involve my.mybatis.PRPMapper.saveParamsToDB-Inline ### The error occurred while setting parameters ### SQL: UPDATE MY_FILTERS SET GROUPS = ' ? ',' ? ' , TEMPLATES = ' ? ' where ID = ? ### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index ; invalid ResultSet access for SQL []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: ...`

Comment: @Andrej: you are right I missed single quote escaping; I update the response. did you also used ${item}?

Comment: Thank you, it was my mistake first, i didn't used `$`. Finally it works with `open="'" separator="," close="'"`